# Adding multiple layers in CartoDB using createLayer() not working

Tags: google-maps, layers, carto

Using CartoDB (cartodb.js 3.5.02), it seems like you should be able to add multiple, independent tile layers to an instantiated Google Map.

I've tried using createLayer() a number of ways, using both viz.json and dynamic SQL and no matter what I do, only the last createLayer's tiles are displayed. (e.g. If I use viz.json, both legends are shown but only one set of tiles.)

Example loading 2nd layer on 1st layer's `done()`:

```
cartodb.createLayer(map, url1)
    .addTo(map) // ultimately not displayed
    .done(function (layer) {
        console.log('added url1 ',url1);
        cartodb.createLayer(map, url2)
        .addTo(map) // displays OK
        .done(function (layer) {
            console.log('added url2 ',url2);
        })
        .error(function (){
            console.log('problem adding 2nd layer');
        });
    })
    .error(function () {
        console.log('There is something wrong with requested data!');
    });
```

Example using dynamic SQL:

```
cartodb.createLayer(map, {
    user_name: 'validusername',
    type: 'cartodb',
    sublayers: [
    {
        sql: 'SELECT * FROM '+tbl1,
        cartocss: '#'+tbl1+'{polygon-fill: #FF6600; line-color: #FFFFFF; line-width: 1; polygon-opacity: 0.7; line-opacity: 1;}'
    }]
})
.addTo(map)
.done(function(layer) {
    console.log('added ',tbl1);
    console.log(map.overlayMapTypes.length); // ==1
}).error(function(layer) {
    console.log('problem loading cartodb layer');
});

cartodb.createLayer(map, {
    user_name: 'validusername',
    type: 'cartodb',
    sublayers: [
    {
        sql: 'SELECT * FROM '+tbl2,
        cartocss: '#'+tbl2+'{polygon-fill: #FF6600; line-color: #FFFFFF; line-width: 1; polygon-opacity: 0.7; line-opacity: 1;}'
    }]
})
.addTo(map)
.done(function(layer) {
    console.log('added ',tbl2);
    console.log(map.overlayMapTypes.length); // still ==1
}).error(function(layer) {
    console.log('problem loading cartodb layer');
});
```

I'm guessing that createLayer() resets gmap's map.overlayMapTypes on each call, as its length == 1 even after the second call. Is there a better way to do this, or is this a bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*addTo* method has a second parameter which is the layer order. In that case you should specify the layer order so, the example would be:

```
...
.addTo(map, 0)
.done(function() { 
 ....
 addTo(map, 1)
```

In any case, done callback receives the layer (which is a google maps layer) so you can use the google maps way to add a layer:

```
done(function(layer) {
  map.overlayMapTypes.setAt(0, layer);
})
```

I've created a working example:

http://bl.ocks.org/javisantana/8527856b8f883d7ce11d

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, Javier! I went back to the API doc and found this as the only reference to the additional param - may be a bit buried?

"You can call to addTo(map[, position]) in the promise so when the layer is ready it will be added to the map."